# How to print view hierarchy of a specific view controller?

Tags: swift, debugging

I issue the following call in the console and got the view hierarchy.

(lldb) expr -l objc++ -O -- [[[UIWindow keyWindow] rootViewController] _printHierarchy]

```
<TestViewController 0x13ee07360>, state: appeared, view: <TestView 0x13ed10520>
   | <MyApp.MenuController 0x13ee126b0>, state: disappeared, view:  (view not loaded)
   | <UINavigationController 0x13ee15b60>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x13ed16b80>
   |    | <MyApp.ViewController 0x13ee13b50>, state: appeared, view: <UIView 0x13ee1d700>
```

How do I print the view hierarchy for MyApp.ViewController? Can the address of the view controller be used somehow?

Comment: Did you try `expr -l objc++ -O -- [0x13ee13b50 _printHierarchy]`, where 0x13ee13b50 is the address of MyApp.ViewController?

Comment: @MartinR That works, can you put this down as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enter the lldb command

```
expr -l objc++ -O -- [0x13ee13b50 _printHierarchy]
```

where 0x13ee13b50 is the address of the view controller that you are interested in.